# How to dispose a streamController when the screen is not pop?

Tags: flutter

Because I used navigate pushNamed to screen B (I want to keep the current screen (Screen A) in the stack), the dispose function of the StatefulWidget in Screen A is not triggered, the stream is still there.
So how I know the navigate pushNamed to Screen B then I can close the stream? And restart the stream when I come back to Screen A.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
navigate()async{

    streamSubscription.cancel();
    await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('routeName');
    streamSubscription = streamController.stream.listen((event) { });

}
```